# Android Drawable Importer doesn't seem to support my Image file

Tags: java, android-studio, android-drawable-importer

I installed ADI so I can import pictures into my app. Some were imported smoothly but some have a problem, It doesn't display any error message but I can not see my imported picture.

| **What I do(1)** | **What I do (2)** |
| --- | --- |
| [image: What I do(1)] | [image: What I do (2)] |

but the plugin does not display my selected file

**Result:**
[image: Result]

and I saw this in Android studio Welcome.

**Error:**
[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

A small hint:

Resource file names are limited to a-z, 0-9, and underscore characters.
They also can´t start with a number.

E.g. `8 (About us).jpg` isn´t possible.

Try renaming all resources accordingly and then try again.

You can also load the images into Android Studio by opening the destination folder in Windows Explorer and copy them into the folder. You don't have to import each image separately.

If that doesn't help, there are probably other reasons. In order to assess this, we would need sample code and a more detailed description.